# Verify order details for cancelled transaction in mastercard payment gateway

Tags: payment-gateway, mastercard

I have implemented MPGS in website. I followed this link for the integration, https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/api/documentation/integrationGuidelines/hostedCheckout/integrationModelHostedCheckout.html.

Everything seems to be working. After successful transaction, I am redirected to website and resultIndicator is getting appended to the URL.

But, when user clicks on cancel in the payment gateway page, I am redirected to the website page but, nothing is being appended to the URL. How can I get something resultIndicator like so that I can check whether the transaction is a valid one?

Answer (score 0):

The gateway provides you callback function to handle `cancel` and `error` events.

```
<script src="https://ap-gateway.mastercard.com/checkout/version/52/checkout.js"
            data-error="errorCallback"
            data-cancel="cancelCallback">
 </script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  function errorCallback(error) {
     console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  }
  function cancelCallback() {
      console.log('Payment cancelled');
  }
 </script>
```

`resultIndicator` is appended only upon successful completion of the transaction. Since it's a cancelled transaction, you do not need to verify if it's a valid one.